# use of inner join query

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

and i m not able to understand the difference between the below clause as even without inner join the result is coming out to be the same.. plzzz help!!!! i tested this on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

---

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders,Customers
where Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 1):

In term of behaviour, they both will return the same thing without any performance issue.

However, people normally prefer the `Join` syntax as this is more clear what you are trying to do.

**Edit** : Some people will claim that the `where` is less clear because it can be used for other validation then a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Both are joins, first one is explicit second one is implicit.

If you want to know more -> [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073088/where-implicit-inner-join-vs-explicit-inner-join-does-it-affect-indexing).